# Is there an online source of complete documentation on Pandas objects/classes (besides reading its code)?

Tags: pandas

Today, I was looking for a long time on the page http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html , trying to find something very simple: an attribute or method that would retrieve the index from the DataFrame. It doesn't show any. I scanned the page many times, as well as doing text searches through it.

Then, of course, I came to stackoverflow and got the answer almost immediately: DataFrame.index is the attribute.

Obviously, in the future, I want to be able to trust the documentation and not waste time like today. So my question is: Is there an online source of complete documentation on Pandas objects/classes (besides reading its code) that doesn't omit any attributes/methods/etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Read [*10 minutes to pandas*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). The [third section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#viewing-data) makes use of the .index attribute.

See also the [tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) section of the docs.

IMO both online documentation and docstring help is very good for specific methods, that said it's difficult to be better than Google/StackOverflow for finding the answer to specific questions...

Comment: I have read tutorials -- months ago. Granted, I don't use pandas every single day. But I don't think I should have to look through tutorials again to find an attribute/method. That's what the docs should be for.

Comment: @qg_jinn index and column should appear on the attributes list, perhaps it's worth opening a [Github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues).

Comment: I bet the doc authors figured that if it's listed in the parameters, people will guess it's also an attribute (i.e. might have been on purpose). Feel free to add a bug report though. I don't have an account and I'm too security conscious to give my info to yet another company/web site (not for such a  small issue, anyway).

Comment: Here is the issue about it: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11407 And normally all attributes are included in the documentation, it is a technical issue that only `index` and `columns` are not